# How to access hyperlink inside pdf?

Tags: java, android, pdf

I want to show pdf inside android app.that pdf contains images with hyperlink when i click that image it will load a webview and show A webpage.it works in google chrome.but while showing pdf via webview its not working.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

        //---you need this to prevent the webview from
        // launching another browser when a url
        // redirection occurs---
        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());

        String pdfURL = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=mypdfhere";
        webView.loadUrl(
                "https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdfURL);

        setContentView(webView);
    }

    private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                WebView view, String url) {
            return (false);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: im getting pdf like this.actually this pdf contain images]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the excellent barteksc library without a web browser. Supports hyperlinks within the document

https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer